# Word 2002 mail merge "command strings"

Tags: microsoft-word, mail-merge

We have an MS Word 2002 document used for mail merge operations. Apart from the usual mail merge fields that one sees when pressing Alt+F9 (show field codes), it also contains strings that look like this:

```
!R! PSRC 1; DUPX 0; EXIT;
```

I have since figured out that "PRSC" sets the printer source tray and "DUPX" turns duplex printing (on both sides of the same page) on or off, but I'm looking for documentation about these and haven't been able to find anything from Google. A contact is calling these "command strings" but I'm not sure how accurate that is.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These commands are printer specific (will not probably work on other brands/models).
Quick googling turned up for example this pdf file:
http://www.kyoceramita.com.au/support/Legacy%20Docs/ComRef.pdf

Comment: Aha! Yes, we are using a Kyocera printer so this makes sense. I tried searching for "!R!" on Google which didn't get me anywhere. I guess I have to improve my Google-fu some more. Thank you so much!